# Updating a newly added column in existing table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables `REPORT` with `RPT_ID` and `RPT_NM` columns

```
RPT_ID   RPT_NM  
2345     UNIVERSAL
3456     FIELD
4567     BOILER
5678     NORTHLAND
5789     CANADA
```

and another table `JOB` where `RPT_ID` column is added which is foreign key and its data is like below

```
JOB_NBR   DOC_NM              RPT_ID
23        FIELD_0             NULL
34        BOILER_2            NULL
45        BOILER_4            NULL
56        CANADA-REVISED_5    NULL
67        UNIVERSAL_23        NULL
```

I need to update this column from `REPORT` table on join on `RPT_NM` and `DOC_NM` but `DOC_NM` does not exactly match.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, ***please*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! That way, you don't need any of those messy `<br/>` and `&nbsp;` tag, either!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Update JOB set RPT_ID=r.RPT_ID
FROM REPORT r
WHERE JOB.DOC_NM like r.RPT_NM+'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that DOC_NM in JOB up to the first '_' or '-' matches RPT_NM in REPORT otherwise this solution will not work.

```
UPDATE j
  SET j.RPT_ID = r.RPT_ID
FROM REPORT AS r
  INNER JOIN JOB AS j
    ON r.RPT_NM = SUBSTRING(j.DOC_NM, 0, CHARINDEX('_', j.DOC_NM))
    OR r.RPT_NM = SUBSTRING(j.DOC_NM, 0, CHARINDEX('-', j.DOC_NM))
;
```

You can use the [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) function along with the [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) to match up JOB's DOC_NM up to the first '_' or '-' to REPORT's RPT_NM.

Here is the solution on SQLFiddle if you want to play around with it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/46c3f/9